# How do I properly implement debounce time here so that it fires only once per time limit in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, rxjs, event-handling, hammer.js

## Goal

I am trying to accomplish the following:

There is a slider/slidehow/carousel/whatever you want to call it, and I want it to register a touch event only once every 3s when you swipe to the right or left. For that I wrote the following code:

```
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let debounceTimer
    return function () {
        const context = this
        const args = arguments
        clearTimeout(debounceTimer)
        debounceTimer
            = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay)
    }
}

if (location.pathname === "/") {
var backgroundElement = document.querySelector('.carousel');
hammer = new Hammer(backgroundElement)
    hammer.on('panright panleft', function (event) {
        //console.log(event.deltaX);
        if (event.deltaX > 250) { 
        debounce(carousel.next(), 3000);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (event.deltaX < -250) {
        debounce(carousel.previous(), 3000);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

## Problem at hand

The problem is that if I keep on swiping after swiping it switches the slides continously back and forth it seems, so neither my debounce implementation or `event.preventDefault();` appears to be working.

How do I fix this to have the intended functionality?

P.S. I would prefer not using RxJS just for this single functionality, I think that's an overkill.

## UPDATE

I'm ok with using Lodash and I've tried implementing my code but I'm getting errors.
My "new" code is:

```
if (location.pathname === "/") {
    var backgroundElement = document.querySelector('.carousel');
    hammer = new Hammer(backgroundElement)
    hammer.on('panright panleft', function (event) {
        console.log(event.deltaX);
        if (event.deltaX > 250) {
            //_.debounce((event)=> { carousel.next(); }, 1000);
            _.debounce(nextSlide(), 1000);
            //event.preventDefault();
        }
        if (event.deltaX < -250) {
            //_.debounce((event)=> { carousel.previous(); }, 1000);
            _.debounce(prevSlide(), 1000);
            //event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    )};
```

My errors are (which trigger when I swipe on the carousel):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function
```

## UPDATE 2

Heck, I'm so desperate that I'm even ok with using RxJS now, but my code does not work due to syntax mistakes. I would appreciate if an answer showed the mistake. My code prototype is the following:

```
if (location.pathname === "/") {
    var backgroundElement = document.querySelector('.carousel');
    hammer = new Hammer(backgroundElement)
    hammer.on('panright panleft', function (event) {
        console.log(event.deltaX);
        if (event.deltaX > 250) {
            //_.debounce((event)=> { carousel.next(); }, 1000);
            _.debounce(nextSlide(), 1000);
            //event.preventDefault();
        }
        if (event.deltaX < -250) {
            //_.debounce((event)=> { carousel.previous(); }, 1000);
            _.debounce(prevSlide(), 1000);
            //event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    ).pipe(
        map((event.deltaX) => event.deltaX.debounceTime(1000))).subscribe(x => console.log(x);)
    )
};
```

the console.log is only to test the filtering I would add the slide changing behaviour if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var delayHandler = debounce(function(event) {
    //console.log(event.deltaX);
    if (event.deltaX > 250) {
        carousel.next();
    }
    if (event.deltaX < -250) {
        carousel.previous();
    }
}, 3000);

hammer.on('panright panleft', function (event) {
    delayHandler(event);
});
```

Comment: now it doesn't work at all for some reason :/

Comment: sorry, see it wrong. i have updated my answer :)

Comment: the new edit doesn't work either :/

Comment: you could try my new new version :))

Comment: doesn't work either :/ there were no errors the whole time